# How to protect against zip bombs from xlsx files?

Tags: javascript, java, zip, xlsx, unzip

I have a system where the client will send the files through HTTP requests which are then processed in the back end. The concern is that xlsx files can act as zip bombs. Given this, are there a) services that allow you to process and unpack files on their side? b) Does it make sense to extract the data on the client side, check the size, and rezip it before sending? Wouldn't that just use the client's resources for this?

Any other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: What are you using to process it on the backend? Excel itself has a check to prevent zip bombs if you're using the provided COM object. If not, zip files contain a header that has the decompressed size of every file so you can simply add those up to get the total uncompressed size and decide whether or not to reject it based on that.

Comment: It will be processed using java. I appreciate the response, but I read in other SO posts that nested files won't get caught by just reading the header. You would have to go through it recursively. Others mentioned that reading headers offers some protection but can be by passed